# Opencart 1.5.6.4 reset password doesn't work

Tags: opencart

I "forgot my password" query 2 days don't come. I found crypter code from *catalog>model>account>**customer.php***

```
sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($your_password)));
```

With reference to I changed my admin password 2 days ago. I still can't login admin panel.

I deleted; caches, cookies but doesn't work still.
I don't understand.

How to solve this? Where is the issue? I can't found it two days.

Thank you for interest.

Best regards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`md5` is sufficient to manually insert a password into the user table:

```
UPDATE user SET password=md5('your_password') WHERE username = 'your_user_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the database connection in /config.php and /admin/config.php are the same - I had a similar problem and found the database connection for /admin/config.php was incorrect.